# Django Fixtures: Importing Nested Models

Tags: python, json, django

New to Python and Django and trying to import a .json file. The JSON file is structured in such a way that each root-level object has a nested object within it.

For example, the JSON is structured as:

```
[
{
    "model": "testapp.Person",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {
        "firstName":"Jane", 
        "lastname":"Doe", 
        "haircolor":"black",
        "mailingaddress": {
            "streetaddress": "1214 Example St.",
            "city": "Silver Spring",
            "state": "MD",
            "zipcode": "20910"
        }
    }
}
]
```

And the python model definition is as follows:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class address(models.Model):
    streetaddress = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def __init__(self, streetaddress, city, state, zipcode):
        self.streetaddress = streetaddress
        self.city = city
        self.state = state
        self.zipcode = zipcode

class Person(models.Model):
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    haircolor = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    mailingaddress = address(streetaddress, city, state, zipcode)
```

Getting an error when running `python manage.py loaddata` because, obviously, the init parameters `streetaddress, city, state, zipcode` don't exist in that context.

How do I construct my model to dynamically generate those other objects?

Comment: did you find any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Basing on your model structure, you'd have to first create an address record. This would then be the record you'd use to save to the Person object you create. So, your fixture would look something like this

```json
[
    {
        "model": "app_name.address",
        "pk": 1,
        "fields": {
            "streetaddress": "1214 Example St.",
            "city": "Silver Spring",
            "state": "MD",
            "zipcode": "20910"
        }
    },
    {
        "model": "app_name.person",
        "pk": 1,
        "fields": {
            "firstName":"Jane", 
            "lastname":"Doe", 
            "haircolor":"black",
            "mailingaddress":1
        }
    },
]
```

Notice that `mailingaddress` has a "1" as a value to denote the primary key of the record, and that's all you'd need.
You could append more people to the same address by just adding another element to the JSON array object.

Another way to ensure you have the right structure for your JSON fixture file is to just add some dummy data (one record should do it) then dump that data to a file (for instance dump.json) and edit that file to meet your needs.

The [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/initial-data/) is also pretty good, so I'd recommend you look into it as well for more guidance.

PS:
You also would not need to have the `__init__` constructor in this case